# Native Debug Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, native

There was such an error when I run Native debugging through Genymotion.

```
Starting LLDB server: run-as org.cocos2dx.cpp_empty_test 
  /data/data/org.cocos2dx.cpp_empty_test/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh 
  /data/data/org.cocos2dx.cpp_empty_test/lldb 
  /data/data/org.cocos2dx.cpp_empty_test/lldb/tmp/platform.port1442313534865 
  "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration
Failed to attach native debugger: Invalid URL: adb://[169.254.67.102:5555]:46216
Invalid URL: adb://[169.254.67.102:5555]:46216
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to attach the debugger to a device. The android platform of target device should have gdbserver agent for remote debugging.

Comment: Try cleaning and re-packaging the app first, worked for me.

Comment: Hello, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

1.in app/build.gradle:

at dependencies label:

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':youModuleName', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':youModuleName', configuration: 'debug')
```

2.in youModule/build.gradle:

at android label:

```
publishNonDefault true
```

demo:

https://github.com/sunalong/JNIDemo

Answer (score 12):

I encounter the same question, and I got the solution to solve it. But I'm not sure weather the solution is good for you.
My solution is: Add the so path in your debug configuration.
1. Open the 'Run/Debug Configurations' dialog;
2. Click 'Debugger' Tab;
3. Add the 'Symbol Directories' with your so path.

My configuration as follow[image]:

Comment: I have added the symbols directory of my library module, then `build/intermediates/cmake/x86_64Debug/obj/x86_64`. This worked well for debugging in emulator using the Active Build Variant "x86_64Debug", for both "Native only" as well as "Dual mode" debugging. If you use a different build variant, you'll likely want to choose a different path.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed all the steps here http://www.akaita.com/post/android-native-library-module-debug/ then you might also be suffering from a bug which is still in Android Studio 2.3.3 which is that the project's IML file gets out of sync with the gradle scripts and gets stuck in the release variant. See the accepted answer on this SO question: [Debug a dynamically loaded native library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570825/debug-a-dynamically-loaded-native-library-in-android-studio).

To quote that answer:
"t turns out this is due to an old bug in AS. Apparently in the past the "SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" in the "native-android-gradle" section in the IML file could become out of step with the actual selected flavour."

To fix this issue, shut down Android Studio and open the IML file for the module that's building the native library (in the case of a single module app, just the app's IML file), and look for "native-android-gradle". For me this had become stuck as the release variant. Manually changing this and restarting got my symbols back.

Comment: First link, to akaita..., is dead.

Comment: You can find the content of the removed article in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180118021059/http://www.akaita.com/post/android-native-library-module-debug/ . Please note that it will look like the page is empty - don't worry, open the browser dev tools, go to "Elements", find the `<body>` element and change its `display` to `block`. That article did not help my with this problem.