# No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration

Tags: android, gradle, configuration, android-ndk

I'm Using Android studio 2.2 and Android.mk file followed this

> https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

c++ files located inside Android module and not in the calling application.
I added to the module the following:

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

there are no errors when I build the project and I can add breakpoints in my java files, but I keep getting No symbol directories found when I try to attach native debugger. when I don't get the error the debugger never stop in any breakpoints inside c++ module files.

I'm using buildToolsVersion "25.0.0", I saw this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202611
still the same error

any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822747/debugging-c-native-libary-modules-not-working-with-android-studio-cmake-used#answer-41867982) or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584177/native-debug-android-studio#answer-42382393)?

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to solve this by doing build APK under Build->build APK.
after the apk was built I run the application as usual and debugger hits breakpoints inside c++ code.

it seems to be resolve in newer Android studio versions.