# Debugging C++/native library modules not working with Android Studio (Cmake used)

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk, cmake

I'm having trouble debugging C++ files of my library module.

Is this possible in general?

The debugging works fine if the application project contains the c++ code.
But I want to move the C++ Code to a library module.

**The Error Message while starting the session:**

Now Launching Native Debug Session

Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration

**gradle file of my lib:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM_LEVEL=${11}",
                    '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
}
```

**In the run configuration the debugger is set to auto**

[image]

---

**Additions:**

**Im using:**

Gradle : 2.2.3

Android Studio : 2.2.3

---

in the LLLB Console, i checked the breakpoint List with:

breakpoint list -v

all my checkpoints are listed there.

**Not Working Breakpoint**

```
1: file = 'C:\android-dev\...\test.cpp', line = 19, exact_match = 0
```

..thats all

**Working Breakpoint**

```
1: file = 'C:\android-dev\...\test.cpp', line = 19, exact_match = 0
    1.1: 
      module = C:\android-dev\...\test.so
      compile unit = gl_code.cpp
      function = testFunc(..)
      location = C:\android-dev\...\test.cpp:16
      address = 0x0000007f871d068c
      resolved = true
      hit count = 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason seems to be, that a release version of the lib is created, 
which does not support debugging, even if the app is built with debug options.

**Solution:**

To solve this issue, do the following workaround. It ensures that a debug version is built.

---

In your apps build.gradle change:

```
compile project(':nativelib')
```

to

```
compile project(path: ':nativelib' , configuration: 'debug')
```

---

In the libs build.gradle add:

```
android {

    publishNonDefault  true //this line

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

**Updates:**

See the google issue for updates:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222276

Comment: In case anyone doesn't want to read the issue linked above, it states that old versions of the Gradle Android plugin used to package a release library, even if the app was set to debug.  However, this has been fixed now, so selecting a debug app will also select a debug library.  Formal docs here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#variant_aware

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error ("Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration."). My solution was (Android Studio 3.2):

Run → Edit Configuration → "Debugger" tab → add your working path to Symbol Directories.

[image]

Comment: What would that 'path to symbol directories' be?  Especially given that multiple native libraries (x86, x86_64, etc) are built?

Comment: @GoZoner To be honest, I just set it to "native libraries" working directory (or directory of your module) and it seems to work fine. See: https://imgur.com/iyo6mzn.

Comment: In Android Studio 3.3.1, I don't seem to be getting any sort of error about no symbol directories found.  However, the debugger would not stop on breakpoints in the native C++ code in my library until I followed the directions from @brkeyal to add a Symbol Directory.  The directory that I added was "library/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj", which contains a folder for each platform (x86, arm64-v8a, etc).  You should also select the "debug" app configuration in the Build Variants window.

Comment: @GoZoner I added the following symbol directories and that then worked fine from there
/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.0/lib64
/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.0/lib

Comment: Tanks !!! This is working very simple to set, but why this is not automatically set or just explained more in debug warning so I don't have to search on so for this..

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue with my own libraries some months ago because I thought that if I added the -g (gcc) flag it would generate the debug symbols, as the desktop (linux, unix kernel) apps.

But, actually it does not work to generate debug symbols.

I see that you use Cmake as a external build tool and clang compiler.

So in my case I configure my **cmake** script with **gcc** but out of gradle scripting, but I think it will be the same, I add -mapcs-frame in the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM_LEVEL=${11}",
                    '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc', 
                    '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static',
                    'DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-mapcs-frame'
        }
    }
```

I know that if you use clang compile may be this flag could not work. But my idea was to share my experience with android native debugging.

I Hope this clues could help you.

Cheers.
Unai.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I tried to compile it with gcc and your arguments. Still have the same problems.

Comment: Maybe you have done, are you using gradle experimental to debug native library? I usually use gradle 0.7.0 experimental

Comment: I use gradle 2.2.3. The Doc says, that it is supported since 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of co-worker who changed the visibility of symbols.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -fvisibility=hidden)
```

After changing the above code to be applied only in release build, debugger(including breakpoints) works fine.