# Android Studio attach to process not finding native symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have followed the steps on the Android developer page on [setting up a CMake project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) to interface with some native code. When I attach to a running process using the native (duel) debugger I get

> Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration

in the debug window output and my breakpoints never get hit. If I create a run configuration and start it to debug from Android Studio (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45096340/467267)) it finds the symbols correctly and the debugger hits my breakpoints. But starting the debug from a run configuration is slower and there are times when I just want to attach to an already running process.

Is there a way to specify the native symbol directories when attaching to a running process in Android Studio 3.3? It seems like the active run configuration doesn't apply in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, ensure that your project is debuggable for both Debug and Release build types. I.e. check below flags are set to true:

```
release {
    debuggable true
}

debug {
    debuggable true
}
```

Then, for C and C++ projects, you can add symbol directories, as well as LLDB startup and post attach commands, in the Debugger tab. To do so, you use buttons similar to the following:

[image]

If you want to add symbol files to provide the debugger with C or C++ information generated outside of Android Studio, you can add one or more directories as shown above.

See more from [Debugger tab](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig#android-application) in Android Studio **Run Configurations**.

And, also check [Attach native debug symbols](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger) which may apply to your case better.

Comment: It still doesn't find the symbols. I don't think the run configuration applies when you're attaching to an existing process. Also your image above has the "LLDB Post Attach Commands" tab highlighted when I think you wanted "Symbol Directories".

Comment: Oops , you are right, I highlighted the wrong tab. Sorry about my mistake

Comment: Adding the root folder to the "Symbol Directory" worked for me.

Comment: @nathan thanks man...adding the root folder was the missing part for me and now i'm working great with AS Chipmunk

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to add the symbols through the LLDB console. Pause the running debugger and switch to the LLDB tab:

```
(lldb) image list
       <list of symbol images already loaded>
(lldb) image add "<path>\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libmylib.so"
```

This still makes me do a lot of manual configuration every time I want to debug. I'd prefer a way to control the default behavior when attaching to an existing process.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Dolphin Gradle version 8 plugin gradle version 7.3.1

1. Go to:
   {Application folder}/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib
2. Select all the folders in the directory  and create a compressed folder.
3. Upload the compressed folder to app bundle in [folders to compress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaC6a.png)playstore.